The tcpdump creates multiple files randomly and starts modifying all
I am troubleshooting an issue where external system reported a delay in response from my side. Therefore, I applied a cronjob for tcpdump that I start when the communication with external system starts. I want to capture all packets during the duration my side communicates with external system.
Cronjob:
39 10 * * * /tmp/tcpdumpEDAissue/capture_traffic.sh

Shell script (capture_traffic.sh):
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -i any host 10.225.42.129 or 10.225.42.130 -C 50 -Xs 0 -vvvv -w /tmp/tcpdumpEDAissue/capture_CallbackEDA_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).pcap

Result:
BT-ISB1-MNSLB1B:/tmp/tcpdumpEDAissue # ls -ltr
total 3792
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     356 Oct 19 10:36 capture_traffic.sh
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2629632 Oct 19 11:20 capture_CallbackEDA_20241019_103901.pcap
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1241088 Oct 19 11:20 capture_CallbackEDA.pcap13
CRBT-ISB1-MNSLB1B:/tmp/tcpdumpEDAissue # 

Issue:
Initially the file 'capture_CallbackEDA_20241019_103901.pcap' started but after sometime another file also appeared i.e. 'capture_CallbackEDA.pcap13'.
As per the tcpdump command the next file should've been created after first file reached 50MB. But here next file created after few minutes and now both have same 'last modify' time.
And second file suffix is '.pcap13'. There is no .pcap12, .pcap11 etc

Welcome to Super User. There is no question in your "question", for now the post is just a story. "Why doesn't it do what I want?" is not equivalent to "how can I make it do what I want?", so don't let us guess what your question is. Please [edit] and ask explicitly.

It looks like you have another process running., possibly something like a systemd timer or some other cron job?

I was running a script for tcpdump using cronjob. Whenever required I was killing the tcpdump script process, but there was another process, that was running the actual tcpdump command given inside the script and it was not being killed. After killing these processes, the script output was OK.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
